# Node.js http: Parse "index of"

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I need to write a Node.js function that finds all available Node.js versions on the official website. To do this, I wanted to receive the content of this link: https://nodejs.org/download/release/, but in form of an array. Is there a way how I can automagically receive and parse the available URLs via some module or do I need to request the site via `http` and then somehow parse the content manually, and if so, how?

Comment: Use any HTML parsing library?

Comment: You can easily pull tags from the [NodeJS](https://github.com/nodejs/node) repository using [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/). Here is the [example](https://api.github.com/repos/nodejs/node/tags?per_page=100)

Comment: @rahilwazir That is so much better than scraping. I want to delete my answer now but I'll leave it up as an example for when scraping is actually required.

Comment: they have a json file with the versions https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/nodejs.org/master/source/versions.json

Comment: @Raulucco Thats even great

Comment: @Raulucco It seems like that file is not updated anymore as newer versions like 5.5.0 are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [rahilwazir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2706988/rahilwazir), you can use a different URL that will give you JSON.

```
var request = require('request');
request( 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/nodejs.org/master/source/versions.json', 
       function(err, resp, json) {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          var data = JSON.parse(json);
          // Do what you need here
       };
);
```

If you really want to scrape the HTML page you mentioned, you could use the following, copy pasted (and adapted) from http://maxogden.com/scraping-with-node.html

```
var $ = require('cheerio');

function gotHTML(err, resp, html) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  var parsedHTML = $.load(html);
  // get all a tags and loop over them
  var links = parsedHTML('a').map(function(i, link) {
    return $(link).attr('href');
  });
}

request('https://nodejs.org/download/release/', gotHTML);
```

Comment: Some feedback on the downvotes would be nice

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but my interpretation of the question was that the OP specifically wanted information from the website, not just a list of all the versions in the world.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Doesn't my answer also show how to scrape it from the mentioned web page? That's what I thought that the downvotes were for, because I answered the question, but there's a better way (through the API), so I added that too.

Comment: Yes, it does. I was attempting to explain why (a) someone may have downvoted, and (b) why the `versions.json` approach may actually not be better. Bear in mind I cannot actually read the minds of downvoters, so debating *me* about it is probably sub-optimal.

Comment: @Dave I know, it's just that you're the only one that provided feedback :)

Comment: That'll teach me! ;)